# Is this an issue in my recursive function?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to run through a stack of HTML Elements. But all my attempts to write a recursive function didn't work.

In the snippet below I cannot `return` value from `if statement` and afterwards from a `function` itself.

I can `console.log` the information I need, it gets there, but trying to `return` it, it doesn't work.

I never had such an issue with returning some data that's why I decided to display it here so as to let a fresh-eye to revise the code.

```
function findElementByDataValue(target: EventTarget, data: {key: string, value: string}){

    if (target.dataset[data.key] === data.value) {
      return target;
    };

    if (target.children.length > 0) {

      for (const child in target.children) {
        const element = target.children[child];

        // I tried to return "recursive" function here too. "Return" Abrupt execution (as it should)
        if (element.children && typeof element === 'object') {
          findElementByDataValue(element, data);
        }

      }

    }

}
```

if you have any ideas or noticed an issue with my recursive function, I would appreciate any help.

Comment: @ASDFGerte I hear that too but return doesn’t work if I return if statement - “return if”. I didn’t have such problems before. Really))

Comment: @ASDFGerte sorry for a stupid question 

Comment: Please read a javascript tutorial. Also, "something's wrong with the second one" is no proper bug description, you don't even say what it is supposed to do.

Comment: I updated my answer, I think I found the bug

Comment: @ASDFGerte return value from the function. Anyways thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `return` keyword like you are doing.

Your second function calls the first function without returning the value returned by the first function:

Replace

```
    if (element.children && typeof element === 'object') {
      findElementByDataValue(element, data);
    }
```

with:

```
    if (element.children && typeof element === 'object') {
      return findElementByDataValue(element, data);
    }
```

In general, run your code in a debugger (popular web browsers provide debuggers) to see what is going on.

See some debuggers documentation:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger
- https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/

If you are new to JavaScript, I suggest looking into [unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) and [test-driven development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_driven_development).

Writing tests (early) will help you think of what can go wrong with your code and write more robust functions. [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/) is nice, this article suggests many other [JavaScript unit testing options](https://raygun.com/blog/javascript-unit-testing-frameworks/)

Comment: I checked many times there. I caught a proper value into the statement. I could console.log it but I couldn’t return. I already tried to return it in many ways. I understand that the problem is not with returning out of the function but I cannot return from the if statement.

Comment: You are calling the 1st function without returning its value. Updating my answer.

Comment: Oh, yes... I was just playing around with that trying to figure out the issue and removed it. But that’s not the issue - tried. Maybe too many hours at laptop today  I guess the issue must be so silly and simple. I thought that a fresh eye can spot it here. Yes, debugging tools are great but they are telling to me that I’ve got a value in my is statement but I don’t know how to let it out and return from the function ‍♂️ maybe I’ll try again a bit later after some yoga ‍♂️ practice 

Comment: Shouldn't your last if just be `if (typeof element === 'object')`? What if element.children is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)?

Comment: no, recursion works well and I can skim over the stack. I can run through all elements and at that first if statement I get the element with the data attribute and value I need, I suppose it’s because for in loop. Just like a clue

Comment: The 2nd function is never called by the first, is it what you want? If you manage to write a small unit test or a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/), we would be able to help further. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks man for your help! I’ll rewrite the recursion in another way and I hope it’ll help. Stupid situation 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205717/discussion-between-pyb-and-valary-o).

Comment: replied to you in the chat