# Did I miss something or this behavior is weird for "if statement"?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I cannot return value from a function. There is nothing fancy or complicated. I just need to run through my `HTMLElements` and return the one I need.

This is the first time it occurred to me, and I spent a lot of time revising the code and trying to return it in a different way or at least understand the reason why it doesn't work.

I would appreciate any help and your understanding.

The snippet below includes the function I am invoking from an event listener invoked with `RXjs - fromEvent`

I believe the code is quite explicit itself but if you need somemore information I'll include my whole code.

```
function findElementByDataValue(target: EventTarget, data: {key: string, value: string}){
  // trying to return by a function
  function send(element) {
    return element;
  }

  if(target && target.dataset){

    if(target.dataset[data.key] === data.value) {
      // console.log(target);
      // send(target);
      return target;
    } else {
      if(target.children){
        for (const child in Object.entries(target.children)) {
          const element = target.children[child];

          findElementByDataValue(element, data);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Here is the whole code on **StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/challenge-credit-card-form)

`*Invoking the function on line:*` **65** 
`*Function on line:*` **34**

Comment: You are missing `return` before the recursive call `findElementByDataValue(element, data);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive function returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12737970/recursive-function-returns-undefined)

Comment: The same story [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59673985/is-this-an-issue-in-my-recursive-function)?

Comment: @ASDFGerte Already solved by the example below. Returing result const

Comment: This is why i was not really happy the last time... You need to review fundamental things about JS/programming, or "simple" things like this will happen over and over.  I mean, you just forgot `return` in front of your recursive call for the second time in eight hours.

Comment: @ASDFGerte That’s the same code but written in a bit different way. I did try to return it but the way I did it didn’t work. Anyway I don’t think it’s worth downvoting. That’s why the source exist - to help as beginners as profs to solve the issues. Have a good day!

Comment: My problem is, that i don't think you are going down a path, that will help you in an efficient way. You are trying, that's nice, and with time you will learn either way. However, there is some fundamental aspect missing, that should have been taught in a good tutorial, and addressing that directly would probably save you a lot of stress and headaches. I sadly can't precisely pin-point what it is (or whether it is only one thing), so i can only give the advice to read another tutorial, and hope, that whatever the last one was missing, will be included that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return the `findElementByDataValue` call if it finds something, otherwise in the `else`, the recursive call won't do anything:

```
function findElementByDataValue(target: EventTarget, data: {key: string, value: string}){
  // trying to return by a function
  function send(element) {
    return element;
  }

  if(target && target.dataset){

    if(target.dataset[data.key] === data.value) {
      // console.log(target);
      // send(target);
      return target;
    } else {
      if(target.children){
        for (const child in Object.entries(target.children)) {
          const element = target.children[child];

          const result = findElementByDataValue(element, data);
          if (result) {
            return result;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried to return the function but it abrupted the execution as it should. You helped me a lot with your example!!! If that's not a burden for you, could you rewrite the function like you would do that? Maybe my recursive function could be shorter or easer. I don't have much experience